# A better way to dynamically embed forms symfony?

Tags: symfony1

I've been using Symfony's form framework for a while now. But would like to know if anyone has a better approach to embedding forms dynamically.

The problem arises when I embed a form (see bottom), I need to give it an array index, as Fabian explains how the sfForm object is like a multi-dimensional array in this article [Advanced forms](http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/06-Advanced-Forms).

If I want to give the user the ability to click a button and embed another form, how can I achieve the following if they click the button multiple times:

```
<input type="parent[child][]" />
<input type="parent[child][]" />
<input type="parent[child][]" />
```

... repeated how many time user clicks a button. I can use fast javascript to copy and paste form elements in DOM.

Rather than this:

```
<input type="parent[child][1]" />
<input type="parent[child][2]" />
<input type="parent[child][3]" />
```

... repeated how many times user clicks a button. Requires javascript method to count how many times user clicks the button, ie to set correct array index. Also requires Ajax to call a PHP function that embeds form with this array index. I would like to avoid using this method if possible.

How I embed a form:

```
$parentForm = new ParentForm($parent)        

$child = new child();
$child->setParent($parent);

$sfForm = new sfForm();
$sfForm ->embedForm($someIndex, new ChildForm($child));

$parentForm->embedForm('child', $sfForm);
```

Comment: In my experience, I've only heard the AJAX method - in fact I'm working on such a module now. What's your motivation for avoiding this?

Comment: I realized that one could duplicate the AJAX functionality in the JS code without actually using AJAX - all the AJAX does is return a bunch of HTML with the form fields, e.g. http://pastebin.com/KwXHcJ3Q . Not sure if this addresses your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey, I found a way to do! The tricky part here is to override sfWidgetFormSchema::generateName method.

```
class myWidgetFormSchema extends sfWidgetFormSchema
{

  /**
   * Generates a name.
   *
   */
  public function generateName($name)
  {
    $name = parent::generateName($name);
    //match any [number] and replace it with []
    $name = preg_replace('/\[\d+\]/','[]', $name);
    return $name;
  }
}
```

Now, you only need to set this to your 'wrapper' form. Here's my example with "Master has many Slaves" schema:

```
  public function configure()
  {
    $this->getWidgetSchema()->setFormFormatterName('list');
    $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('master[%s]');

    $slavesForm = new sfForm();
    $slavesForm->setWidgetSchema(new myWidgetFormSchema);
    $slavesCount = $this->getOption('slaves_count', 2);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $slavesCount; $i++)
    {
      $slave = new Slave();
      $slave->Master = $this->getObject();
      $form = new SlaveForm($slave);
      $slavesForm->embedForm($i, $form);
    }
    $this->embedForm('new_slaves', $slavesForm);
  }
```

Notice the 'slaves_count' option that I pass from executeCreate like this:

```
  public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $schema = $this->getRequest()->getParameter('master');

    $this->form = new MasterNewForm(null, array('slaves_count'=> count($schema['new_slaves'])));

    $this->processForm($request, $this->form);

    $this->setTemplate('new');
  }
```

Now you can easily use jQuery to clone rows and not bother about index! Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for this. Geeez sorry it took me so long to vote it up. I much prefer allowing the user to clone the rows with jQuery. Muuuch better.....

Answer (score 1):

I think you can take a look at ahDoctrineEasyEmbeddedRelationsPlugin 
http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/ahDoctrineEasyEmbeddedRelationsPlugin
Maybe it would be useful even if you don't need to embed related records on doctrine form.

Answer (score 0):

This seems great: http://nacho-martin.com/dynamic-embedded-forms-in-symfony